# How to use Regex Negative Lookahead to fail the match if specific word is found somewhere later in the string

Tags: regex

I want to use regex negative lookahead to fail the match if "exceed" word (in bold) is found later in the string.

**Sample Text:**
aggregate liability of Seller arising pursuant to or in connection with the representations, warranties, indemnifications, covenants or other obligations (whether express or implied) of Seller under this Agreement or any document or certificate executed or delivered in connection therewith shall exceed One Hundred Thousand Dollars ($100,000) (the “Liability Floor”). If Seller’s aggregate liability to Purchaser shall exceed the Liability Floor, Seller shall be liable for the entire amount thereof up to but not ***exceed*** the Liability Ceiling.

**Regex:**
(?(?((until\s*and\s*unless|suffered|(?in?\sany?\s*case?|shall\s*not)\s*)exceed(s)?|aggregate(\s+\S+){0,30}?\s+((?in?\sany?\s*case?|shall\s*not)\s*)exceed(s)?))(\s+\S+){0,30}?\s+(?(((|[)?\s*\$[0-9,.%]*\s*[)|]]?))\s+(?!((?\s*(the)?\s*“?deductible“?\s*)?)))(\s*\S+){0,30}?\s+((reimbursement|liable|pay\s*for\s*the?\s*)?\s*\b(full|all|entire)\b\s*(((such)|(amount\s*of))?(\s+\S+){0,30}?\s+(claim(s)?|loss(es)?|damage(s)?|amount))|all\s*indemnifiable\s*((claim(s)?|damage(s)?)|amount|damage(s)?)\s*([(|[]?\s*(including\s*(basket\s*amount|the?\s*amount\s*of?\s*the?\s*basket))[)|]]?)|from\s*the?\s*first\s*dollar\s*(of\s*loss(es)?)?|to\s*dollar\s*zero)**(?!.*(exceed))))**

I have used a negative lookahead at the end of the regex, but it haults if the word exceed is found. If it is not found, regex works fine. Please help

Comment: Recommend you rewrite with a _much_ shorter, minimal example that demonstrates the issue. 2 words? 3 words?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this (tempered greedy token with negative lookup)

```
/(?:(?!exceed).)*$/
```

again the performance might be an issue if you have too much text to go through

Comment: It is getting stuck. However thanks for responding, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using proximity operators like ((\s*\S+){0,30}?\s+) correctly. My issue was resolved by replacing one of the these ((\s*\S+){0,30}?\s+) with (.*?) Although using wildcard is not favorable but if it is the last resort, you must use it with ? lazy operator and specify some language after it.